# rxjs - change single data in two different subscribes - make more reactive

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs-observables

I am pretty new in Angular2+ and RxJs, so I apologise if I am asking some obvious things.

#### Functionality

When the data is just started to load, `startAction` is getting emitted, `isLoaded` turns `false` and the spinner is getting shown.

Once the data is loaded, `endAction` is emitted, isLoaded is being set to `true`. The spinner is getting hide and the main data is depicted.

Once the user clicks another button, another amount of data is getting loaded. `startAction` is getting emitted again, the spinner to be shown again untill the data is loaded.

#### What I have

In component:

```
this.startAction.subscribe(() => {this.isLoaded = false;});
this.endAction.subscribe(() => {this.isLoaded = true;});
```

In template:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="isLoaded; else loading">
  ...data...
</ng-container>

<ng-template #loading>
  <mat-spinner></mat-spinner>
</ng-template>
```

#### What I need

Everything works pretty fine, but I need to rework this approach making it more reactive. I have to get rid of subscribes and turn `isLoaded` into observable to be able to use it via `async` pipe in template.

#### What I tried

In component:

```
isStartLoading = this.startAction.pipe(mapTo(false));
isEndLoading = this.endAction.pipe(mapTo(true));
isLoaded = combineLatest([this.isStartLoading, this.isEndLoading])
  .pipe(takeLast(1)); // does not emit
  //.pipe(last()); // does not emit
  //.pipe(take(1)); // emits only once
```

In template:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="isLoaded | async; else loading">
...
```

#### My explanation

As per my understanding, `takeLast(1)` have to emit the last action among `isStartLoading` and `isEndLoading`. So when `startAction` happens, `takeLast(1)` should emit an observable over `false`, when `endAction` - an observable over `true`.

For some reason I see only the initial spinner, and the result data is not depicted. Looks like I have wrong understanding of how `combineLatest` + `takeLast` should work together.

When I added `tap(console.log)` after `takeLast(1)` / `last()`, I saw that it never emits. But when replaced it with `take(1)`, it expectedly emitted only once. So I saw the spinner, then the data, and then, after clicking another button - newly loaded data with a delay and without spinner, since we taking only the first one.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Is it possible to do without subscribers, only methods like: (click)="startAction()"?

Comment: can you please show the rest of the code? and maybe create a minimal repro on stackblitz? I believe it'd be possible to refactor further using reactive patterns but I'm missing some code there

Answer (score 0):

I would make one new property in redux reducer called ***isLoading*** which will be set to false by default, and then changed in start and end actions to true, false respectively.

Then in your component you can say like this, I assume your reducer is called 'layout':

```
ngOnInit() {

this.isLoading$ = this.store.pipe(select('layout'), pluck('isLoading'), distinctUntilChanged<boolean>());
```

}

and in html you say:

```
<div *ngIf="isLoading$ | async"><div/> else notloading stuff.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your initial solution is very close, but [`combineLatest`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/combineLatest) only emits when both observables have emitted and then continues to combine the latest emissions from the observables.

You can achieve what you are looking for with [`merge`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/merge), as it will emit a value for each observable.

```
const isStartLoading = this.startAction
    .pipe(mapTo(false));

const isEndLoading = this.endAction
    .pipe(mapTo(true));

const isLoaded = merge(this.isStartLoading, this.isEndLoading);
```

Then you can async pipe the isLoaded value.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="isLoaded | async; else loading">
```

Beware as the order of the emission does not matter with `merge`, if `isEndLoading` emits before `isStartLoading` you will have issues.

[`concat`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/concat) may be a better option if you cannot guarantee the order the observables emit as it sequentially emits.

```
const isLoaded = concat(this.isStartLoading, this.isEndLoading);
```

Here is a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-ufadui?devtoolsheight=60) for both examples.